# How to build an AST using PackCC?

Tags: c, parsing, peg, packcc, packrat-parsing

Using [PackCC](https://github.com/arithy/packcc) to generate a parser from a PEG grammar you get a API like this

```c
typedef struct pcc_context_tag pcc_context_t;

pcc_context_t *pcc_create(void *auxil);
int pcc_parse(pcc_context_t *ctx, int *ret);
void pcc_destroy(pcc_context_t *ctx);
```

Since the implementation of `struct pcc_context_tag` is only in the `.c` file, I imagine that it is intentionally "hidden" and I can work with these API. Therefore my question is:

- I can build the Abstract Syntax Tree using the API? Or I need to investigate the `.c` file to understanding the actual implementation of the parser?

As context, I'm trying to store the the AST on a tree like the bellow, where for each PEG file `data` is a pointer for a distinct structure with the information of each node of the AST.

The example [AST Builder for Tiny-C](https://github.com/arithy/packcc/tree/master/examples/ast-tinyc) is not clear to me, no much comments in the code...

Another example is [PegOF](https://github.com/dolik-rce/pegof) (also not clear to me), I can't find on it a subroutine to convert `pcc_context_t` to `struct AstNode`.

```c
typedef struct tree_s {
   void *data;
   struct tree_s *first_children;
   struct tree_s *next_sibling;
} tree_t;
```